# Restoring SQL database from backup as different user

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-restore

I am trying to programatically restore an SQL database backup using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`.

This is my code so far:

```
        Server corp = new Server(SQLServerName);
        Restore restore = new Restore();
        restore.Database = databaseName;
        restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        restore.Devices.AddDevice(LocalBackupFilePath, DeviceType.File);
        restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 5;
        restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        restore.PercentComplete += DatabaseRestorePercentComplete;
        restore.Complete += DatabaseRestoreComplete;

        DataTable dbFiles = restore.ReadFileList(corp);
        string backupLogicalName_MDF = dbFiles.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        string backupLogicalName_LDF = dbFiles.Rows[1][0].ToString();
        restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(backupLogicalName_MDF, @"G:\Databases"));
        restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(backupLogicalName_LDF, @"G:\SqlTranslogs"));

        restore.SqlRestore(corp);
```

When I execute this it gives this error:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Restore failed for Server '<server>'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'G:\Databases'.
```

From what I read, this is because the user the code is running as doesn't have the right permissions. I don't know what user the code is running as, neither how to change it.

Could you, please, advise me if there is a way to solve this without changing the user and if not - how to change it?

Comment: That's not a SQL Server error. `Access Denied` is most likely caused by *file* permissions. Does your account have permission to access those folders?

Comment: Does the SQL Server Service Account have access to `LocalBackupFilePath`? The fact that the variable has the name "Local" suggests to me it's stored on your device (not the server), so the likely answer is "no".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah I do, that's why I'm assuming the code is running as another account under the hood.

Comment: @Larnu, the file is stored on the SQL server and the code is ran on the SQL server. I guess it should but I do not know for certain. Can you advise me how to check?

Comment: The Restore will run as the service account that SQL Server uses, @J.Doe, not your user.

Comment: @Larnu, is that because of the `Restore` object and the way the `smo` library works or is it just an SQL-specific thing?

Comment: *"Can you advise me how to check?"* Navigate to the folder the backup file is stored in in File Explorer and right click it. Go to the Permissions Pane. What permissions does the SQL Server Service account have in that fodler?

Comment: When ever you attempt to access a file with SQL in SQL Server the permissions of the Service Account is used. If Agent is trying access it it would be agent. If you're executing an SSIS Package, then whomever started the package would have their credentials used. I.e. `RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak';` would use the the SQl Server Service Account to try to access `Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak` not yours (even if you executed the SQL).

Comment: @Larnu, unfortunatelly the SQL service account isn't listed in the Permissions tab and I do not have the rights to change permissions in any way. Furthermore from looking up accounts I see three SQL service accounts in our user directory and am not sure which is doing the work.

Comment: At this stage, you're better off talking to your DBA and Network Administrator then

Comment: @Larnu, bleh, so no chance of changing which user does the restoring?

Comment: No, the Service account **needs** access to the backup file. That is how SQL Server is designed to work.

Comment: @Larnu, but why can I restore it manually from SQL Management Studio but it throws an exception from my code? DBA also confirmed the SQl service account has access to the folders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200659/discussion-between-j-doe-and-larnu).